# Set the adapter on text drawable in recycle view

Tags: android, adapter, android-recyclerview

Text drwable cannnot be set on the `RecycleView`.

```
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_row, viewGroup, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    ExpensesTable nature = expensesItem.get(i);
    viewHolder.category.setText(nature.getCategory());
    viewHolder.money.setText(nature.getMoney());
    viewHolder.date.setText(nature.getDate());
    viewHolder.time.setText(nature.getTime());
    viewHolder.notes.setText(nature.getNotes());
    TextDrawable drawable = mDrawableBuilder.build(String.valueOf(nature.getCategory().charAt(0)), mColorGenerator.getColor(nature.getCategory()));
    viewHolder.imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}
```

I am try to this but can not set the adapter of textdrwable but it's show me `NullPointerException` on adapter

[image: error page]

Comment: Where do you initialise your `TextDrawable`?

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/2252830)

Comment: where is your 66 line ? maybe your mDrawableBuilder is null ,you need to initialize mDrawableBuilder in your constructor first。